# Surroundings moves faster than the subject?

Tags: video

How to edit/shoot a scene where the **person(subject)** in center moves normally while the **surroundings(background)** moves faster?

Example:

I'm walking in the street but the cars and other people that passes me are faster than me.

**P.S.** I can't find it in youtube or other blogs because I don't know the term of this kind of technique yet.

BTW, I am a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about I.e. the effect used in this video by orbital: https://youtu.be/ymu_ogcXigg...  this is done by letting run the camera in time lapse mode and moving very slowly, making the surrounding appear very fast.

Comment: Actually I already thought about that but I saw a lot of scene where the subject moves normally (not moving slowly then time lapse the surrounding)..

I will look like not moving normally when I will do that technique. But if that's the only way, then I'll try my best to move slowly but looks like natural in output.

Thanks.